# HTML and MVC C# passing values via forms

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms

I am working with a form in C# and MVC.

I need to pass aNameID to `example.com/controlpanel/edit/{anameID}` rather than `example.com/controlpanel/edit/?a={anameID}`.

How can I do this?

Here is my code:

```
<form action="http://example.com/controlpanel/edit/" method="GET">
<label for="male">Person ID #</label>
<br />
<input type="text" name="aNameID"  style="width:70px;"/>
  <input type="submit" name="submit"  />
</form>
```

Comment: Try calling it 'ID', or set up a route for it?  MVC3 is set to run with ID as a default parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery to hook into the form's submit event, then modify the action of the form and submit it yourself:

```
$("form").submit(function() {
  var $form = $(this);
  var id = $("input[name=aNameID]").val();
  var newAction = $form.attr("action") + id;
  $form.attr("action", newAction);
  $form.submit();
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Did not seem to work, I place the code within the page with the form, do I put it where the action is? action="http://example.com/controlpanel/edit/"

Comment: Did you wrap it in a `<script/>` tag? and a `$(document.ready(function()...` ?

Comment: yep within script tags, but what do you mean by "and a $(document.ready(function()..."

Comment: You need to ensure that the document has been rendered before hooking into the submit event. Check out http://api.jquery.com/ready/